# Java Process Crash - Java Finalizer

Tags: java, crash

This is happening on a network application using JGroups library and a simple RMI server for storing and retrieving text files. Normally it happens when I am closing the application although sometimes it happens while running. I am not sure if this happens on windows since I haven't tested that recently. When this error happens I am getting a print on the netbeans console saying about invalid memory access.  Any suggestions on possible causes are welcome.

```
Process:         java [16180]
Path:            /usr/bin/java
Identifier:      com.apple.javajdk16.cmd
Version:         1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  java [3237]

Date/Time:       2012-04-04 20:02:35.865 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          213989 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           -4
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  22680 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   -2
Anonymous UUID:                      368E726E-03C9-45EA-A019-631C4374BC4D

Crashed Thread:  8  Java: Finalizer

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001035c2000-00000001035ca000 [   32K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release
objc[16180]: garbage collection is OFF

Java information:
 Exception type: Bus Error (0xa) at pc=7fff95c00390

 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.6-b01-413 mixed mode macosx-amd64)

Current thread (7f86d184e800):  JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=178642944, stack(10a95e000,10aa5e000)]
Stack: [10a95e000,10aa5e000]
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.font.AppleNativeStrike.disposeNativeStrikePtr(J)V+0
j  sun.font.AppleNativeStrike.finalize()V+13
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+0
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer()V+45
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Ljava/lang/ref/Finalizer;)V+1
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  7f86d18be000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=288497664, stack(111222000,111322000)]
  7f86d18f4800 JavaThread "ViewHandler,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_blocked, id=287436800, stack(11111f000,11121f000)]
  7f86d3829000 JavaThread "Connection.Sender [192.168.1.2:10900 - 192.168.1.2:61215],Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_blocked, id=286375936, stack(11101c000,11111c000)]
  7f86d3828000 JavaThread "Connection.Receiver [192.168.1.2:10900 - 192.168.1.2:61215],Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_in_native, id=279425024, stack(11097b000,110a7b000)]
  7f86d3830800 JavaThread "Connection.Sender [192.168.1.2:10900 - 192.168.1.2:61210],Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_blocked, id=276242432, stack(110672000,110772000)]
  7f86d380f800 JavaThread "Connection.Receiver [192.168.1.2:10900 - 192.168.1.2:61210],Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_in_native, id=180469760, stack(10ab1c000,10ac1c000)]
  7f86d1a64800 JavaThread "Timer-5,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=338313216, stack(1141a4000,1142a4000)]
  7f86d3806800 JavaThread "OOB-2,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_blocked, id=337252352, stack(1140a1000,1141a1000)]
  7f86d3805800 JavaThread "OOB-1,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_blocked, id=336191488, stack(113f9e000,11409e000)]
  7f86d3804800 JavaThread "Timer-4,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=335130624, stack(113e9b000,113f9b000)]
  7f86d3804000 JavaThread "Timer-3,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=334069760, stack(113d98000,113e98000)]
  7f86d3803000 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=331956224, stack(113b94000,113c94000)]
  7f86d31fa800 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=281546752, stack(110b81000,110c81000)]
  7f86d18a9000 JavaThread "RMI RenewClean-[192.168.1.2:61200]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=280485888, stack(110a7e000,110b7e000)]
  7f86d19d0800 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=278364160, stack(110878000,110978000)]
  7f86d18f7000 JavaThread "Incoming-2,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_blocked, id=277303296, stack(110775000,110875000)]
  7f86d18f3800 JavaThread "Incoming-1,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_in_Java, id=188440576, stack(10b2b6000,10b3b6000)]
  7f86d31b6800 JavaThread "Timer-2,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=275181568, stack(11056f000,11066f000)]
  7f86d1ae2000 JavaThread "ConnectionMap.Acceptor,null,null" [_thread_in_native, id=274120704, stack(11046c000,11056c000)]
  7f86d31b6000 JavaThread "TransferQueueBundler,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" [_thread_blocked, id=273059840, stack(110369000,110469000)]
  7f86d1ae1800 JavaThread "DiagnosticsHandler,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=271998976, stack(110266000,110366000)]
  7f86d1acc800 JavaThread "Poller SunPKCS11-Darwin" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=270938112, stack(110163000,110263000)]
  7f86d1acb000 JavaThread "Timer runner-1,Default Channel,ILMBP-61076" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=269524992, stack(11000a000,11010a000)]
  7f86d3290800 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=268464128, stack(10ff07000,110007000)]
  7f86d1a06000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=267403264, stack(10fe04000,10ff04000)]
  7f86d1801800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=67104768, stack(103eff000,103fff000)]
  7f86d31ca000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=261455872, stack(10f858000,10f958000)]
  7f86d18c6800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=260395008, stack(10f755000,10f855000)]
  7f86d31ec800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=192757760, stack(10b6d4000,10b7d4000)]
  7f86d3194800 JavaThread "AWT-AppKit" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2066884960, stack(7fff629c2000,7fff631c2000)]
  7f86d3054800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=185786368, stack(10b02e000,10b12e000)]
  7f86d3054000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=184725504, stack(10af2b000,10b02b000)]
  7f86d3053000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=183664640, stack(10ae28000,10af28000)]
  7f86d3052800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=182603776, stack(10ad25000,10ae25000)]
  7f86d1862800 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=181542912, stack(10ac22000,10ad22000)]
=>7f86d184e800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=178642944, stack(10a95e000,10aa5e000)]
  7f86d304d800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=177582080, stack(10a85b000,10a95b000)]
Other Threads:
  7f86d3049000 VMThread [stack: 10a758000,10a858000] [id=176521216]
  7f86d305e000 WatcherThread [stack: 10b131000,10b231000] [id=186847232]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)
VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 par new generation   total 19136K, used 2958K [7f3000000, 7f44c0000, 7f44c0000)
  eden space 17024K,   4% used [7f3000000, 7f30d3a20, 7f40a0000)
  from space 2112K, 100% used [7f40a0000, 7f42b0000, 7f42b0000)
  to   space 2112K,   0% used [7f42b0000, 7f42b0000, 7f44c0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 63872K, used 5065K [7f44c0000, 7f8320000, 7fae00000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 37696K, used 26941K [7fae00000, 7fd2d0000, 800000000)

Code Cache  [10416d000, 1043de000, 10716d000)
 total_blobs=657 nmethods=137 adapters=482 free_code_cache=49396928 largest_free_block=18368

Virtual Machine Arguments:
JVM Args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
Java Command: gui.AppInterface
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
Physical Memory: Page Size = 4k, Total = 7936M, Free = 29M


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b6067a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b5fd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8da8d6fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8da95e64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8da95676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff918cb31f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff918d25c9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff918d2456 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f274f5d _DPSNextEvent + 659
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f274861 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
10  libawt.jnilib                   0x000000010b4530a5 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f27119d -[NSApplication run] + 470
12  libawt.jnilib                   0x000000010b3ff674 +[AWTStarter startAWT:] + 1495
13  libawt.jnilib                   0x000000010b3fefee -[CPerformer perform] + 93
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8daf075d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
15  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8b562d94 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 214
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8da6f6e1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8da6ef4d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8da95d39 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8da95676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
20  java                            0x00000001035c6843 0x1035c2000 + 18499
21  java                            0x00000001035c629a 0x1035c2000 + 17050
22  java                            0x00000001035c3a98 0x1035c2000 + 6808

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b6067a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b5fd71 mach_msg + 73
2   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813ed3 0x103800000 + 81619
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813da4 0x103800000 + 81316
4   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813d12 0x103800000 + 81170
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038138ed 0x103800000 + 80109
6   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813712 0x103800000 + 79634
7   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038cf65c 0x103800000 + 849500
8   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038cf1c1 0x103800000 + 848321
9   java                            0x00000001035c5286 0x1035c2000 + 12934
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a58bf _pthread_start + 335
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a8b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 2:: Java: Exception Handler Thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b6067a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b5fd71 mach_msg + 73
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b6031c mach_msg_server + 641
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103814d99 0x103800000 + 85401
4   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103814c53 0x103800000 + 85075
5   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813854 0x103800000 + 79956
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a58bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a8b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: Java: Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b6067a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b5fd71 mach_msg + 73
2   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813ed3 0x103800000 + 81619
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813da4 0x103800000 + 81316
4   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813d12 0x103800000 + 81170
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038138ed 0x103800000 + 80109
6   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813793 0x103800000 + 79763
7   libclient64.dylib               0x000000010382c578 0x103800000 + 181624
8   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813854 0x103800000 + 79956
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a58bf _pthread_start + 335
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a8b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: Java: Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b6067a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b5fd71 mach_msg + 73
2   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813ed3 0x103800000 + 81619
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813da4 0x103800000 + 81316
4   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813d12 0x103800000 + 81170
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038138ed 0x103800000 + 80109
6   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813793 0x103800000 + 79763
7   libclient64.dylib               0x000000010382c578 0x103800000 + 181624
8   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813854 0x103800000 + 79956
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a58bf _pthread_start + 335
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a8b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: Java: Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b6067a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b5fd71 mach_msg + 73
2   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813f65 0x103800000 + 81765
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103832b1e 0x103800000 + 207646
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038138ed 0x103800000 + 80109
5   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813793 0x103800000 + 79763
6   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001039088a1 0x103800000 + 1083553
7   libclient64.dylib               0x000000010390878b 0x103800000 + 1083275
8   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103832999 0x103800000 + 207257
9   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813854 0x103800000 + 79956
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a58bf _pthread_start + 335
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a8b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: Java: VM Thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b6067a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b5fd71 mach_msg + 73
2   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813f65 0x103800000 + 81765
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103832b1e 0x103800000 + 207646
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038138ed 0x103800000 + 80109
5   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813793 0x103800000 + 79763
6   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038aa578 0x103800000 + 697720
7   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038aa2b7 0x103800000 + 697015
8   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813854 0x103800000 + 79956
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a58bf _pthread_start + 335
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a8b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: Java: Reference Handler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b6067a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b5fd71 mach_msg + 73
2   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813ed3 0x103800000 + 81619
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813da4 0x103800000 + 81316
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b8b7f 0x103800000 + 756607
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b800c 0x103800000 + 753676
6   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b7c78 JVM_MonitorWait + 154
7   libjvmlinkage.dylib             0x000000010369cb0b JVM_MonitorWait + 59
8   ???                             0x000000010417dd6e 0 + 4363640174
9   ???                             0x000000010417285a 0 + 4363593818
10  ???                             0x000000010417285a 0 + 4363593818
11  ???                             0x000000010416d438 0 + 4363572280
12  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038ab736 0x103800000 + 702262
13  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b77c4 0x103800000 + 751556
14  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b76ba 0x103800000 + 751290
15  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b765a 0x103800000 + 751194
16  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b74fc 0x103800000 + 750844
17  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b7311 0x103800000 + 750353
18  libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813854 0x103800000 + 79956
19  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a58bf _pthread_start + 335
20  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a8b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 8 Crashed:: Java: Finalizer
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff95c00390 objc_msgSend_vtable14 + 16
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8da65ca0 CFRelease + 176
2   libawt.jnilib                   0x000000010b434076 Java_sun_font_AppleNativeStrike_disposeNativeStrikePtr + 42
3   ???                             0x000000010417dd6e 0 + 4363640174
4   ???                             0x000000010417285a 0 + 4363593818
5   ???                             0x000000010416d438 0 + 4363572280
6   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038ab736 0x103800000 + 702262
7   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038ab4fa 0x103800000 + 701690
8   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038ba662 0x103800000 + 763490
9   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001039a1b28 0x103800000 + 1710888
10  libjava.jnilib                  0x00000001040054cb Java_java_lang_ref_Finalizer_invokeFinalizeMethod + 88
11  ???                             0x000000010417dd6e 0 + 4363640174
12  ???                             0x000000010417285a 0 + 4363593818
13  ???                             0x000000010417285a 0 + 4363593818
14  ???                             0x000000010417285a 0 + 4363593818
15  ???                             0x000000010416d438 0 + 4363572280
16  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038ab736 0x103800000 + 702262
17  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b77c4 0x103800000 + 751556
18  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b76ba 0x103800000 + 751290
19  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b765a 0x103800000 + 751194
20  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b74fc 0x103800000 + 750844
21  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001038b7311 0x103800000 + 750353
22  libclient64.dylib               0x0000000103813854 0x103800000 + 79956
23  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a58bf _pthread_start + 335
24  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff949a8b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96b627e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8bbc55be _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8bbc414e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54
```

--- Threads deleted due to length limit ---

```
Thread 43:: Java: Image Fetcher 0
0   ???                             0x0000000104222a58 0 + 4364315224

Thread 8 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0xa00000001037e07d  rbx: 0x00000001037e0b40  rcx: 0xa00000001037e07d  rdx: 0x00007fff7a411760
  rdi: 0x00000001037e0b40  rsi: 0x00007fff7a3e0580  rbp: 0x000000010aa5d3c0  rsp: 0x000000010aa5d378
   r8: 0x000000010417c8a0   r9: 0x000000010aa5d690  r10: 0x000000010417dd41  r11: 0x0000000103c445a3
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x00000007fb999e10  r14: 0x00007f86d184e9d0  r15: 0x00007f86d298f038
  rip: 0x00007fff95c00390  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x000000010ac1e000
Logical CPU: 0

--- binary images deleted----

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 5
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 118704
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=156.0M resident=73.8M(47%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=82.2M(53%)
Writable regions: Total=464.3M written=73.4M(16%) resident=109.9M(24%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=354.4M(76%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
ATS (font support)                 31.8M
ATS (font support) (reserved)         4K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
CG backing stores                  5300K
CG image                           1036K
CG raster data                      128K
CG shared images                   3448K
CoreGraphics                         16K
CoreServices                       1336K
Java                              260.5M
Java (reserved)                    40.0M        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC                             53.2M
MALLOC guard page                    64K
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)            2048K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Mach message                          8K
Memory tag=242                       12K
STACK GUARD                        56.2M
Stack                              50.8M
VM_ALLOCATE                        16.6M
__CI_BITMAP                          80K
__DATA                             14.1M
__IMAGE                             528K
__LINKEDIT                         48.6M
__RC_CAMERAS                        240K
__TEXT                            107.5M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        50.8M
shared memory                      2428K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             747.0M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    705.0M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical bit is

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.font.AppleNativeStrike.disposeNativeStrikePtr(J)V+0
j  sun.font.AppleNativeStrike.finalize()V+13
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

I would google for similar failures but an upgrade of the JVM if not the OS is most likely the fix.

Comment: Guess I need to test on windows to know if its the JVM. Thanks for the advice Ill look for it now.

Comment: Its low level enough that its more likely to be something the JVM only does on Mac OS.  If you can try a different JVM on Mac OS that would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue. It's on Mac only and happens more often when there's text rendered on a Graphics2D with drawString method. Didn't figure out yet exactly what's the problem and if there's a workaround, but I suspect that it has to do with Mac's JRE implementation because it works fine on Windows.

Comment: For me the problem was caused From a deep cloning library I was using. Once I changed the way of cloning with my own implementation the crash stopped.

Comment: interesting because I am using RITS deep cloning library. Which one were you using and what did you change it to?

Comment: Was using http://code.google.com/p/cloning/ and replaced it with my own implementation.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info, I was using the same. Will get rid of it, that crash has been a major pain in the neck.

Comment: Cant tell if its a bug of the library, or I was using it wrong, but definitely check it.